# vue change div from component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**html**:

```html
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='custom'>
        <div class='item'> 1</div>
        <div class='item'> 2 </div>
        <div class='item'> 3 </div>
      </div>
      <component-vue />
    </div>
```

**Vue**:

```js
    methods: {
      doSomething() {
       document.querySelector('.custom).innerHTML = /new items
     }
    }
```

My question is, is this the only way to change the external div? I need to change `items`, new ones come from api. Maybe there is another way? If only through `innerHTML`, then how can I implement the idea?

Comment: You can use an iterator `v-for` and a `items` data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```html
<div class="item" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"></div>
```

```js
data() {
   return {
      items: []
   }
},
methods: {
    doSomething() {
       // Fetch data from api and load
       this.items = res.data
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

```html
<div class='custom' v-html="dataHtml"></div>
```

```js
data() {
   return {
      dataHtml: `
      <div>Initial html</div>
      `
   }
},
methods: {
    doSomething() {
       // Fetch data from api and load
       this.dataHtml = createHtml(res.data) // Fictional method to parse data and transform to html f.e.
   }
}
```

Comment: apparently, I poorly explained what I need. Sorry. :c
html is written in ```ruby ​​on rails```, I would like to influence the ```custom``` class from the component. We leave the layout for SEO, and then, if I click the buttons in the filter, we redraw the html

Comment: Then try a `v-html`. I will add to answer.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you need to write this in general vue, it will not work out of ```compoent-vue```

Comment: If vue.js is just in `component vue`, my response didnt work for it, you only can use vainilla. But if the vue app is initialized in a parent, that works.